# Pandas DataFrames for GPS Coordinates lookup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, gps

I've got a Pandas DataFrame with a collection of Google Maps API reverse lookups saved by latitude and longitude coordinates, and another DataFrame with IoT GPS coordinates and timestamps of those coordinates.

In order to reduce the number of requests to Google API (which are not cheap), I want to, whenever I have already fetched the coordinates, look-up on my DataFrame instead.

The reverse lookup df looks like:

```
lat     lng       address 
47.001  -122.027  Seattle, WA USA
46.320  -122.034  Portland, OR USA
```

My GPS data looks like:

```
lat.   lng.     timestamp. 
47.001 -122.027 2020-03-14T00:15:00
47.001 -122.027 3030-03-14T00:30:00
```

and so on.

For each row in the GPS DataFrame, I want to lookup whether I have the reverse lookup already. If so, return the address. If not, well, I can hit Google Maps API and fetch it, update the reverse lookup df.

How do I compare the `lat` AND `lng` from DataFrame `df_rev_lu` (the reverse lookup data) to the `lat` AND `lng` of the `df_gps` DataFrame (the GPS data), ensuring that the values of both row and column (cell?) for the pair are an exact match, for each row of the `df_gps` DataFrame?

Comment: whats the gps data, a json request? do you transform it into a dataframe in your script?

Comment: Yes, they’re both transformed to DataFrames by the time I implement this step.

Comment: try `pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['lat','lng'],how='inner')` it will return matches based on your gps cords, you can then update your incoming df, or just remove the rows that don't match by boolean filtering.